# How to remove UIimageView from Superview

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiimageview, uiimage, objective-c++

In my application I am adding a `UIimage` on every button click. As user can add that image number of times he clicked button, I have attached a tag "count1" with that button, and count increases on every click. Thus i can differentiate every image with its tag.

Now i want to remove all those images, on another button click.

I tried to remove those images through the following piece of code

```
for (int i=1; i<=count1; i++) 
    {
        UIImageView *imgRemove;
        [[imgRemove viewWithTag:i] removeFromSuperview];

    }
```

but my application is crashing when I press the button.

please help...

Comment: How many cells do you have in your table?

Comment: What makes you think it's loading 3 times?

Comment: Paste some more code. What is imgPimple? Why don't you just keep the pointer to the imgView and then call `[imgView removeFromSuperView]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove a view form the super view look at this question (with answer): [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516294/uiview-what-is-the-correct-way-to-remove-a-subview-from-a-view-hierarchy-and-nuk)

Comment: I go through that link buton pasting that code also my application is getting crashed. Please help.